# Cannot get Workflow/Trigger to identify Read Email on Case object

Tags: trigger, workflow, email2case

I'm facing a problem when I try to implement a functionality that lets users see if there is a unread Email on a Case, indicated by an icon in a formula field. I have a workflow rule that adds the icon when an email is received on a Case, by setting a checkbox the following rule criteria was fullfilled on the EmailMessage object:

```
 (Email Message: Is Incoming equals True) and (Email Message: Status equals New)
```

In the formula field checking the checkbox value and set the appropirate icon, this works fine. The checkbox is set and the icon is added. But when I try to remove the icon when the Email's status changes from New to Read I could not get my other workflow rule to fire, also on the EmailMessage object with the following rule criteria:

```
 (Email Message: Is Incoming equals True) and (Email Message: Status not equals New)
```

I could not see anything indicating that i had fired in my debug logs. So I started writing a Trigger that were supposed to set the checkbox to False (onBeforeInsert and onBeforeUpdate):

```
Set<ID> caseIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(EmailMessage message : newList){
        if(message.Incoming == true && message.Status == 'Read'){
            caseIds.add(message.parentId);
        }
    }
    List<Case> csUpdateList = [select id, New_Email__c from Case where id IN :caseIds];
    for(Case c : csUpdateList)
        c.New_Email__c = false;

    update csUpdateList;
```

This still doesn't solve the problem and nothing is shown in my debug logs, I'am obviously missing something but I cannot figure out what. What is the best way to recognice that an Email has been read (opened)? I assume it is checking the Status, and if so, what is the best way to "catch" this event? 
If I could solve this with workflows I would prefer it, but any help with the Trigger is highly appreciated.

Ciao!

Comment: how about a report - cases with email message, where email status = new?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to consider is to use a VF page as an element within your standard Case page layout.

- The VF page is associated to a controller with access to the Case id
- The controller can query the children of the Case (that is, EmailMessage)
- The controller can thus display on the VF page a message indicating an unread EmailMessage (and links too)

**Downsides?**

If you need to use SFDC reports to report on Cases w/ unread emails (or List Views) - these won't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is kind of what I started implementing as an idea yesterday, I'm gonna make the icon clickable with an url to a VF page that will just redirect me to the email page. And the logic for everything else will be in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, that action doesn't generate a DML execution. As far as I know there are no workarounds available.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000biKgAAI

Comment: Thanks for your answer, been seraching for anything about this but I must have missed that link. Do you know if the same thing applies for Comments on a Case? Meaning, is it possible to implement the idea I'm searching for in question for Case Comments? An icon showing a new comment and when the User clicks in to the case it dissapears?

Comment: @You can do it for case comments. I have done it a few times before.

Comment: It's interesting that the Appexchange app Email to Case Premium has this feature included, including a workflow rule to alert the user if there is a new message. They seem to copy all the emails into Comments to achieve this. It's a good package. Have a look at it, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the workaround Implementation explained on YouTube:
https://youtu.be/AL13GE4vYe0

In summary:

Add a Custom checkbox field 'New Email?' on case to let users know whether a new Email Arrives in the case.

Add an inline blank VF page on Case page layout, that invokes a controller to update the New Email flag whenever a Email's status is either New or Read.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you at least try to summarize?

Comment: @AdrianLarson

- Having Custom checkbox field 'New Email?' on case, to let users know whether  a new Email Arrives in the case.
- Inline blank VF page on Case layout , invoking a controller to update the New Email flag whenever a Email's status is either New or Read.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any additional content.